# How to disable WordPress from automatically changing "x" to multiplication symbol "×" when typing numbers that also contain an "x" between them?

Tags: posts

I simply want to be able type, for instance, "7x12 house design". WordPress, however,  automatically changes x (alphabet) to × (<- this is a multiplication symbol special character): "7×12 house design".

How can I disable this?

Comment: can you please provide a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of [wptexturize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/), which includes a number of other transforms such as generating en- and em-dash symbols, ellipses and curly quotes. ([Here's the specific code for this](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5.3/wp-includes/formatting.php#L290), known as 'multiplication symbol' in the documentation but 'times' in the code.)

You can disable wptexturize completely with

```
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );
```

but there's no built-in way to disable just this one wptexturize rule.

Comment: Thanks for your support! It worked.