# Wordpress converting ' to ’ and - to –?

Tags: posts, categories, tags

When I create a post (or whatever) in wordpress if i type - wordpress converts it to – on site for public users.

as you can see left one is bigger than right one (i added right to just show what i mean
[image: )]

And when I type ' wordpress converts it to ’.
[image: .]
in this one left one is the one i added so you can see why right one is wrong

how can I fix it so wordpress won't convert it like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is [wptexturize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/) which includes a number of other transforms too.

You can disable wptexturize completely with

```php
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );
```

which you can put in your child theme's functions.php, or in a one-file plugin or similar. I can't see a way to disable just these rules specifically.

Comment: (I've written [a similar answer before](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/379140/3276), but to a different question)